# CM action on cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $A/F$ be a CM abelian variety over a number field and $R$ its ring of endomorphisms (a CM order). Is $H^{1}(A(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Z})$ a locally free $R$-module of rank one?